# show that harmonic series is divergent with $ \sum_{n=2^{k}+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{n} \geq\left(2^{k+1}-2^{k}\right) \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm pretty stuck with this exercise. Hope somebody can help me:

show that
$$
\sum_{n=2^{k}+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{n} \geq\left(2^{k+1}-2^{k}\right) \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
and use this to show that the harmonic series is divergent.

First I can't figure out how to show the inequality.
Second I'm not quite sure how to use the inequality to show divergence. Because it doesn't really help letting k go to infinity.

---

Writing out the series gave me this, but where do I go from here:
$$
\sum_{n=2^{k}+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2^{k}+1}+\frac{1}{2^{k}+2}+\cdots \frac{1}{2^{k}+2^{k}}=\frac{1}{2^{k}+1}+\frac{1}{2^{k}+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}
$$

---

**Edit:**
So I understand how to show the inequality now. Thanks!
But I'm still lost with how to use the inequality for the divergence proof.

Comment: How many terms are in the partial sum and what is the smallest of them?

Comment: @Surb are there $2^{k+1}-(2^k+1)=2^k-1$ terms? And the smallest term is $1/2^{k+1}$

Comment: Almost, actually there are $2^{k+1}-(2^k+1)+1=2^{k+1}-2^k=2^k$ terms (try with $k=1$).

Comment: Anyway, these two observations should help you to get the desired inequality.

Comment: To conclude the proof, just note that $\sum_{n=2}^{2^{k+1}} = \sum_{m=0}^{k}\sum_{n=2^{m}+1}^{2^{m+1}}$

Comment: @Surb I really don't get that part?

Comment: Are you saying that: $\sum_{n=2}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{m=0}^{k} \sum_{n=2^{m}+1}^{2^{m+1}}\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: yes that is the point

Comment: @Surb Thank. That makes sense now.
I would never realise that on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact
$$
\sum_{n=2^{k}+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2^{k}+1}+\frac{1}{2^{k}+2}+\cdots \frac{1}{2^{k}+2^{k}}\ge \frac{1}{2^{k}+2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{k}+2^k}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{k}+2^k}=(2^{k+1}-2^k)\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac12.
$$

Comment: Thanks. But how do I use this to show that the series is convergent?

Comment: It diverges, the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac1n
 \ge \sum_{n=1}^{2^k} \frac{1}{2^k+n} 
 \ge \sum_{n=1}^{2^k} \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}
 = \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \sum_{n=1}^{2^k} 1
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: So the last part give me 1/2. But how to I use this to show that the series is divergent?

Comment: @sjm23 so the original sum is now at least $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac12$

Answer (score 0):

(I am summarizing in this answer the steps discussed with OP in the comments)

Let $k\geq 0$ be an integer.

First note that the sum $\sum_{n=2^{k}+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{n}$ has $2^{k+1}-(2^{k}+1)+1= 2^{k+1}-2^k = 2^k$ terms, that is
$$\sum_{n=2^{k}+1}^{2^{k+1}} 1 = 2^k\tag{$*$}$$

Second, note that
$$\frac{1}{n}\geq \frac{1}{2^{k+1}},\qquad \forall n\, \text{ s.t. }\,2^{k}+1\leq n\leq 2^{k+1}\tag{$**$}$$

Combining the above observations, we have
$$\sum_{n=2^{k}+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{n}\,\overset{(**)}\geq\,\sum_{n=2^{k}+1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\,=\,\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\sum_{n=2^{k}+1}^{2^{k+1}}1\,\overset{(*)}{=}\, \frac{2^k}{2^{k+1}}\,=\,\frac{1}{2}\tag{$*\!*\!*$}$$

Now, note that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{n}\,\geq\, \sum_{n=2}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{n}\, =\, \sum_{m=0}^k\, \sum_{n=2^{m}+1}^{2^{m+1}}\frac{1}{n} \, \overset{(***)}{\geq}\, \sum_{m=0}^k \frac{1}{2}\, = \, \frac{k+1}{2}$$

As the above holds for every $k\geq 0$, by letting $k\to \infty$, we conclude that the harmonic series diverges.